# update related data in razor pages

Tags: razor-pages

In the visual studio documentation, in "Working with Data in ASP.NET Core", section ["Updating related data - EF Core Razor Pages (7 of 8)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1)  I have some trouble trying to understand how the `Html.Row()` method works in this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            @{
                                int cnt = 0;

                                foreach (var course in Model.AssignedCourseDataList)
                                {
                                    if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                                    {
                                        @:</tr><tr>
                                    }
                                    @:<td>
                                        <input type="checkbox"
                                               name="selectedCourses"
                                               value="@course.CourseID"
                                               @(Html.Raw(course.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                               @course.CourseID @:  @course.Title
                                    @:</td>
                                }
                                @:</tr>
                            }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

How exactly does `Html.Row()` method work? 
Is there an alternative in updating a related entity in a many to many relationsip?

Answer (score 1):

By default, all strings rendered within an Razor Page (or View) are [encoded as HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2) - that is all HTML characters are converted to their HTML entity. This is a security measure to help the novice developer form introducing potential XSS attacks into their site.

The `Html.Raw` method does not encode the string. It is intended to be used for rendering HTML in a Razor Page. I don't understand it's use in the snippet you reproduced. It's pointless. The following will achieve the same thing:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedCourses" value="@course.CourseID" checked="@course.Assigned" />
```

If the value of `course.Assigned` is `true`, the `checked` attribute is rendered. Otherwise it isn't.